# Lenovo firmware update fails with Error 105

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, fwupd

I keep seeing that there are firmware updates pending on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 6th Gen running Kubuntu 21.10. When I install them either using the GUI or the command line `fwupdmgr update` and restart the machine, I see the following error show up during boot:
[image]

```
SCT Flash Utility for Lenovo
  for Shell V1.0.4.9
Copyright (c) 2011-2019 Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
Copyright (c) 2011-2019 Lenovo Group Limited. 

Usage: ShellFlash64 [COMMAND]...

Try 'ShellFlash64 -help' for more commands. 

ERROR 105 - Command line error!
Reset System
```

After that, the computer boots normally but it did not update the firmware so the update manager pesters me again about pending updates. Is this a known issue? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure this update tool is for Ubuntu and not for Windows?

Comment: [This does seem to be a known issue](https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-lenovo/issues/201#issuecomment-1059422392). Hopefully an update to `fwupd` in the near future will resolve it ...

Comment: @matigo -- yup, that's the issue. Hopefully, it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Meanwhile you may want to install it as OS agnostic.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Lenovo firmware updates on my Thinkpad running Kubuntu. It seems like a known problem, and some users are hoping for a fix in future updates. In the meantime, someone suggested trying to install it as OS agnostic. By the way, have you checked out the SCT Flash Utility tool for Lenovo? It might be worth exploring as it could potentially help with the firmware update. I found a helpful article about it that you might want to check out . Hope it helps!